# Optimizing binary string splitting for maximum score

Tags: c

I am a beginner to C language and have been trying out a question on Leet code :

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:**
*Given a string s of zeros and ones, return the maximum score after splitting the string into two non-empty substrings (i.e. left substring and right substring).

The score after splitting a string is the number of zeros in the left substring plus the number of ones in the right substring*

**Here is my try:**

```
c language
int maxScore(char* s) {
    int length=strlen(s);
    //int count_zero=0;
    int arr[length];
    int s_zero=0;
    int s_one=0;
    int sum=0;
    
    for(int n=0;n<length;n++)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
        {
            if(s[i]=='0')
            {
                s_zero+=1;
            }
        }

        for(int j=n+1;j<length;j++)
        {
            if(s[j]=='1')
            {
                s_one+=1;
            }
        }

        sum=s_zero+s_one;
        arr[n]=sum;
        s_zero=0;
        s_one=0;
        sum=0;
    }

    int ans=arr[0];

    for(int i=0;i<length-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<length;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]>arr[j] && arr[i]>ans)
            {
                ans=arr[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return ans;

}
```

It has passed testcases (100/104) but is not passing the testcase when input is '110000'. It is giving output as 1 instead of 3. Please tell me where I am going wrong in my code. Please do also keep in mind that I am a beginner who just got his hands now on C language.

Comment: Please revise your question with a [mre], i.e. a program instead of a snippet.

Comment: If your program returns 2 then it one side is empty which is a bug per your specification.

Comment: When I run your program  `maxScore("00") == 1` so I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Spliting 00 in two means 0  and 0 . As you said in the question ``` The score after splitting a string is the number of zeros in the left substring plus the number of ones in the right substring``` So it will count as 1 zero in left 1 zero in right --> score will be 2 only.

Comment: @AllanWind How it will come as 1?? it has 2 zeros

Comment: @Arun You count 0 on left side and 1 on the right side, and as neither can be empty it's count_0("0") + count_1("0") == 1.

Comment: @Arun Op will have to clarify but the correct answer is 1 and that is was the program returns for the input "00".

Comment: yes @AllanWind it gives the correct answer. I read it wrong. neeraj what is the issue?? can you give a reproducable input?

Comment: @Allan Wind @ Arun Op I'm really sorry, its giving me 1 instead of 3 for input 110000. Actually I am not able to edit my question

Comment: @NeerajMansingh Please revise question with failing test case (you should assume that people don't read the comments).  Why can't you edit your question?

Comment: @Allan Wind I am also not sure but I had edited my question thrice after posting it and now after clicking on edit it is not showing anything .  If possible could you tell me how to edit it please

Answer (score 1):

1. `for(int n=0;n<length;n++)` should be `n < length - 1` as it's invalid to split at `n=length-1`.
2. (Optional) Using separate loops for scoring the left and right partition is perfectly fine, but combined they sweep through all of `s` so could do that in single loop by counting 0s before the split (inclusive) `n` and 1s after (exclusive).
3. (Minor) `for(int i=0;i<length-1;i++)` could start at `i=1` as you initialize `ans = arr[0]`.
4. `for(int j=i+1;j<length;j++)` is incorrect as `arr[length-1]` isn't a valid split (per 1.).
5. To find the maximum value `ans` of an array you only need to iterate through it once (`O(n)`).  What you have works (other than 4.) but it's unnecessarily slow (`O(n^2)`).

Combine all the above and rename variable for common usage (`n` is often used for length, `i` and `j` as index variables) you get this `O(n^2)` algorithm:

```
int maxScore(const char *s) {
    int n = strlen(s);
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < n-1; i++) {
       int score = 0;
       for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
           score += (j <= i && s[j] == '0') + (j > i && s[j] == '1');
       if(score > ans) ans = score;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Another approach is to accumulate the count of 0s from the left in the array `zero`.  The score for the left partition is `zero[i]`.  The score for the right position has `n-i-1` numbers (0s or 1s) so we need to subtract the 0s of which there are `zero[n-1] - zero[i]` to find how many 1s there are.  This has a run-time of `O(n)`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t maxScore(const char *s) {
    size_t n = strlen(s);
    if(n < 2) return -1; // error

    size_t zero[n];
    zero[0] = s[0] == '0';
    for(size_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
        zero[i] = zero[i-1] + (s[i] == '0');

    size_t max = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        size_t score = zero[i] + (n - i - 1 - zero[n-1] - zero[i]);
        if(score > max) max = score;
    }
    return max;
}

int main(void)  {
    printf("%zu\n", maxScore("110000"));
}
```

The output of either implementation is:

```
3
```

Comment: I like this approch but please could you tell me what is the problem in my code because of which I am output for '110000' as 1 instead of 3

Comment: how it will be 3 @NeerajMansingh??? splitting 110000 will be 110 & 000. 0 on left 1 & 1 on rights is 0. So it will be 1 only.

Comment: @Arun The optimal split is "11000" and "0" with score of 3 + 0 = 3.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to the thorough answer by Allan Wind, here is an alternative implementation.

The idea is to do a first pass over the string to determine its length and count the number of zeroes (equal to the score if the left substring could be the entire string).
Then the split is moved towards the left while the score is updated according to the value of the element being moved to the right substring:

```
unsigned maxScore(const char *s)
{
    unsigned score = 0;
    unsigned n = 0;
    while(s[n] != 0)
    {
        if(s[n] == '0') score++;
        n++;
    }
    unsigned scoreMax = 0;
    while(n >= 2)
    {
        n--;
        if(s[n] == '0') score--;
        if(s[n] == '1') score++;
        if(score > scoreMax) scoreMax = score;
    }
    return scoreMax;
}
```

Comment: Neat.   For the first loop suggest either `s[n]` or `s[n] != '\0'`. Don't variables and functions share the same name space?

Comment: Super minor but maybe move `unsigned maxScore = 0;` after the first loop to minimize it's scope?

Comment: @AllanWind Yes, it was a bit confusing that I had a variable with same name as the function, I have changed that. Also moved it to minimize scope, I agree that is a good habit. Have kept the `s[n] != 0, though, as I think that is more a question of style(?). Thanks!